# network issue with Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2

I have Hyper-V installed on a Windows 2008 R2 system.  I have 4 IPs and they are assigned as such:

the Host machine has one
I had 3 VMs with Windows Server 2003 that each took one.

I deleted one VM and remade it because I had made the hard drive too small.  After the install of Windows Server 2003 I added the ip from the deleted VM to the new one.  Windows claims it is connected.  In fact i can ping the other 2 VMs and the host machine.  When I attempt to connect to the internet it wont connect.  If i ping www.google.com i get the message that it can not find the host www.google.com.  I have verified that I have all the settings correct.

Has anyone ever had this problem and solved it?

Thank you.

Comment: can you ping the gateway via ip?

Comment: yes i can ping the gateway.  I can also ping the other assigned ip addresses to me.  I can not, however, ping the dns server.  It seems i can only ping ips within my subnet.

Comment: try this  - telnet ipadressofdnsserver 53 - do you get an active disconnnect or does it just hang?

Comment: could not open connection to host, on port 53:connect failed

Comment: look for the vmc files associated with this vm, within that you'll see the mac, check to see if its unique on this particular hosts. Not likely but this problem is strange to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone suggested that it might be my ISP.  They had binded the ip to the MAC address of the original server, so when i created a new server the MAC was different.  Thanks everyone and especially tony roth for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You mention IPs, but there looks like no mention of virtual NIC type. You might check to ensure that the virtual NIC is set for bridged (if you want two-way network access) or at least NAT (if just outgoing access is needed).

Comment: Well it works with the other VMs so i doubt it has to do with the network setup.  Honestly I think it has to do with the fact that the IP was attached to another VM that has since been deleted.

Comment: The IPs (other than the ones specifically assigned to the physical adapters of the hypervisor) is not tracked anywhere across the hypervisor...

Answer (score 0):

First check to make sure your Virtual Networking is set up as External and not Internal or Private.